# Does "shape" also mean "assemble"?

Tags: meaning

> I prefer the retailers that help shape the products/services I buy.

I couldn't find the exact definition that "shape" can be interpreted as "assemble".  In the example above, what does "shape" mean? Does "shape" mean to come up with what to buy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Shape** is used here in the sense of **formulate, design, refine, facilitate** rather than **assemble**.

It has more to do with envisaging and planning than actually putting things together.

**Assembly** is the final stage of production. **Shaping** is part of the process that leads to it.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shape_2